# Tag wiki entries

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about writing a short wiki entry for some of the set theory related tags (at least those I'm able to write), but then I realized that I have absolutely no idea what and how to write it.

Is it possible that someone picks up the glove, and writes at least one tag wiki (or is there a way to find one written up?) so that we can have some "standard" to conform to?

Personally I'd hate to think that I'm the first one to do so.

Comment: I had written one for notation after a plethora of questions, not sure if that is "standard" worthy, though.

Answer (score 5):

I've just written a few tag-wiki excerpts. As of now, the first page of our popular tags all have tag wikis.

It'd be great if

1. People can look over the those wikis and see if there can be improvements. (Obviously, the fact that the space is limited makes it a bit difficult.)
2. We can manage to have wikis for, say, everything in the top three pages in terms of popularity. (Pages 2 and 3 are already half full.)

Please bear in mind that when writing a tag-wiki, one of the important function is **disambiguation**. For exmaple, it'd be great if [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis) and [complex-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers) can be clearly separated. (This is also related to our recent discussion about [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition).)